# Why isn't VIM storing macros across sessions?

Tags: vim, macros

In VIM 7.3 on Ubuntu Server 12.04.1, VIM forgets macros and registers after closing. I do have `set nocompatible` in `.vimrc` and the command `:set viminfo?` gives this result:

```
viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
```

What might be preventing the macros and registers from being stored across close / open?

Note that I am not interested in storing mappings for long term use in `.vimrc`. Rather, sometimes (such as during refactoring) I need to perform a simple operation on a few files and I find it easier to do in VIM than with Perl. I just need the macros and registers stored across open / close, which I do have working on other servers.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the register contents actually stored? You can check with `less +/Registers: ~/.viminfo`. Also, check whether the file belongs to / is writable by your user.

Comment: @Ingo: Please post that as an answer. `.viminfo` was actually owned by root for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: When you have something that works on context A and doesn't on context B the very first thing to do is to compare setups on A and B. Did you do that? Is there any difference?

Comment: Thanks, romainl. In fact, I thought that I checked everything relevant but I did not check `.viminfo` ownership. There is always something additional relevant!

Comment: Ah, glad I could help. I actually recently had the same problem on a new VM, this was caused by first running `sudo vim`; I've expanded this into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are the same as (named) registers.
You can check whether the register contents are actually stored with the following shell command:

```
less +/Registers: ~/.viminfo
```

Also, (e.g. when you've executed `sudo vim` and there wasn't yet a `.viminfo` file), the viminfo file may be not writable by your user, so your changes won't persist any more; check with

```
ls -l ~/.viminfo
```

that your user is the file owner and the permissions are alright. (Fix with `chown` / `chmod`.)

Comment: Thanks. `.viminfo` was in fact owned by root.